# replace() jquery замена "div"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите,правильно оформить функцию `replace()`.
Мне нужно заменить это значение на пробел:

```
$("#b").click(function() {
  var el = $('#t');
  el.val(el.val().replace("<div class=\'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e\' style=\'z-index: 90; display: block;\'></div><div class=\'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s\' style=\'z-index: 90; display: block;\'></div><div class=\'ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se\' style=\'z-index: 90; display: block;\'></div>", "g"));
});
```

На вход поступает:

```
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div>
```

Пробовал так, но безуспешно.
Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы видите что подсветка кода нарушена? Вероятно что-то не так в использовании кавычек?

Comment: Проблема не в кавычках

Comment: Откройте консоль браузера и проверьте ошибки там.

Comment: это же как регулярка ,тут оформление особенное нужно ,http://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/nh3gc5tk/

Comment: Все выражение берется в двойные кавычки, но внутри кроме всех одинарных присутствует и одна двойная, вот тут style="z-index: возможно в этом и ошибка.

Comment: Это не "как регулярка", это строка, и кавычки должны её обрамлять. Если внутри строки вам нужны кавычки, либо используйте другой их тип (если обрамляющие двойные, то одинарные и наоборот), либо экранируйте обратным слешем.

Comment: А если вы хотите, чтобы это было регуляркой, то вместо кавычек в начале и конце следует использовать слеши: `.replace(/регулярка/, 'строка на замену', 'g')`.

Comment: @fori1ton,Как то так?

Comment: Не совсем. Если используете внутри двойных кавычек только одинарные, экранировать их не надо. К тому же, вы как-то странно их экранируете, для некоторых слеши стоят до, а для некоторых - после кавычки. Правильно - до кавычки: `"I'm a string with \"double quotes\""`

Comment: Смотрите внимательнее. Часть апострофов вы экранируете правильно: `\'` а часть путаете порядок `'\ ` и в итоге получается ересь `\u` `\z` итп

Comment: слэш кавычка,всегда такой же порядок,я исправил,несложно ли вам посмотреть,где я снова облажался.

Comment: Теперь всё работает правильно. Проверяйте, что вы даёте на вход, возможно, во входной строке используются двойные кавычки. А вообще, облажались вы в тот самый момент, когда решили заменять куски HTML по точному совпадению или по регулярке. [HTML нельзя парсить регулярками](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4863012), используйте средства DOM.

Comment: @fori1ton,Вот на вход поступает строка такая же практически,Я выше указал. А как же быть?

Comment: Для того, чтобы сработала замена, нужно, чтобы поступала не "практически", а точно такая же строка или строка, содержащая точно такую подстроку. А у вас типы кавычек не совпадают. Как быть я вам уже сказал - используйте средства DOM.

Comment: @zkolya посмотрите [сюда](http://jsfiddle.net/wfw2o3o5/1/)

Comment: @eicto,А вы не знаете,в чем может быть дело.В jsfiddle все работает,а в браузере пишет a.find is not function. jquery подключен

Comment: я думаю вы что-то не так написали, наприме `a` у вас не объект jquery

Comment: @eicto,да вроде объект var a = $('#div_1' ).html();

Comment: `a` здесь - строка

Comment: @eicto,нужно преобразовывать как то?

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23504/discussion-between-eicto-and-zkolya).

Comment: @eicto,Через ToString() не помогло

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. На входе кавычки двойные, в условии замены - одинарные.
2. И вообще, это жесть, заменять такую html разметку на букву `g`.
3. `val` - изменяемый текст находится в textarea или input'е? Т. е. элемент с id `t` - это textarea?
4. Если под `"g"` подразумевалось заменить все вхождения, то это не должно работать. Хотя, вроде кто-то такое реализовал.